# How can I see if a int exist in a list without any inbuilt functions?

Tags: f#

First write a function called mem which, given an integer and a list of integers, return true if the integer occurs at least once in the list and false otherwise. This is my first question and I dont want to use any inbuilt functions.

My second question:
Create two functions that each takes two list of integers as arguments and returns the union and the intersection respectively of the lists considered as sets. You will probobly want to use the previosly defined member function. The lists doesn't need to be sorted but they cant have any duplicates.

I have no ide how to solve this without any inbuilt functions
Any solutions?

Comment: Hi, please don't expect us to solve your homework. You should show your attempts first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to learn F#, then you should actually try learning it instead of asking on StackOverflow. However, both of the questions sound like a reasonable questions that can actually demonstrate some basic F# to the rest of the community, so here are some possible solutions.

The member test can be implemented as a recursive function. The idea is that you walk over a list and return `true` if you find the value you need. If you find another value, you need to recursively process the rest of the list. If you reach the end (and find an empty list), then you return `false`, because an empty list does not (obviously) contain the value you're looking for:

```
let rec mem value = function
 | x::xs when x = value -> true
 | x::xs -> mem value xs
 | [] -> false
```

How to implement unioning using `mem`? Well, the union will contain all elements from one list, together with all elements from the other list that are not already contained in the first list (you do not want to create duplicates). So, `union list []` is going to be `list`. If the second list is non-empty (`x::xs`), you want to check if the element `x` is in the first list. If yes, you want to skip it, otherwise you add it to the result:

```
let rec union list1 list2 = 
  match list2 with
  | [] -> list1
  | x::xs when mem x list1 -> union list1 xs
  | x::xs -> x::(union list1 xs)
```

This is not the most efficient solution, because it is not using *tail-recursion*, but it is the simplest one to start with.

Comment: Tomas, I'm having trouble with some homework. Do you mind if I email it to you to look it over? :-)

Comment: @Daniel Sure thing, no problem ;-). Just make sure that the email starts with "Dear Sir", otherwise it may end up in my spam folder. But seriously, I do not know what to do about homework questions - even after reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated - if people ask a homework question, they will eventually get an answer somewhere. This one is at least a sensible example of basic F# recursion...

Comment: Dear Sir, I think your answer and reasoning are both excellent. Warm Regards, Your Fellow SOer.

Comment: I made something like this 'let y = [3; 4; 5; 6]
let x = 4
let mem x y = List.find (fun elem -> elem = x) y 
 
let intersect x y = Set.intersect (Set.ofList x) (Set.ofList y)
let union x y = List.append x y |> Seq.distinct |> List.ofSeq' it works but I cant use the builtin functions